# Updating Versioned .NET Assembly References

Tags: c++, .net, .net-assembly

I have a C++/CLI project that needs to reference a .NET assembly.

I've done so by going into the project properties and clicking "Add New Reference", and browsing to the assembly location (it's not part of the solution, so I cannot create a project-to-project reference, and the .NET assembly is not in the GAC so it isn't in the .NET tab when viewing the references to add)

When the .NET assembly is updated (that is, since it is versioned, it will increment its version number daily), the C++/CLI project fails to compile because it is still referencing the older version.

The workaround I've been doing is deleting the .NET reference and adding it back in, but this is not feasible. How do I have it recognize the newer assembly??

Note: The older assembly is replaced with the newer one, so it is in the same location, but doesn't know that it should use the newer version.

Comment: Add an empty C# project B, which just copy the new .NET DLL to the give location; and let your C++/CLI project depends on that project B. Don't know if it can solve your problem, but I think it worth a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the project with text edit, find the reference tag which reference the .NET Assembly, remove the Hintpath and change the value of include to the relative path of the the DLL, it is  will be like this:

`<Reference Include="\..\.\mydll.dll" />`

You can just copy the value of hintpath to the include tag.

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks. Since the assembly is versioned, my reference tag is a little different: `<Reference Include="MyDLL.dll, Version=30.0.0.72, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"></Reference>`

Comment: I believe that is why he wants you to change it.  Remove the version info from the Reference tag and it shouldn't version check the DLL.  I'd be curious to know if that works.

Comment: I removed the version info and it seems to work. Now that I think about it, I can't think of a case where the version info would be needed (at least, as far as the vcxproj is concerned). I think it is also worth mentioning that if you add a versioned assembly reference to a C# project, it won't add the versioning info. Some reason, the vcxproj file includes it!

Comment: @ScottTx, yes, that's exactly what I mean